# The case of the tags that weren't there because they were scared of my burnination skills, I guess

Tags: bug, status-declined, tags, editor

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900667/i-have-an-url-when-i-paste-in-the-browser-it-was-downloading-and-the-same-url-is) popped into my RSS feed and, of course, I had to take a peek.  The title is captivating.

> [image]

Before voting to close, I tried to edit out the redundant tags, maybe just down to one.  But when I tried, something weird happened.

> > > > > > > > > > [image]

What happened to all those tags?  Maybe someone edited while I was crying at the quality of the question?  But when I refreshed the page, the tags were still there.

I tried a couple more times, and while I noticed that the tags *appeared* to still be there for a fraction of a second (plain text), once the tag formatting kicked in all I was left with were these two tags.  The same thing happens when you edit the entire question.

> > > > > > > > > [image]

But, if you select all text in the textbox, removing the formatting, you do see the tags.

> [image]

Bug?  Also, enjoy my nested quotes.

Comment: I was able to remove the tags that showed, leaving the other 3, but then I thought better of it and rolled back so others could see this delightful behavior for themselves.

Comment: Given the meta-effect can close questions in minutes, I am shocked the question only has 1 close vote after 30 minutes

Comment: @psubsee2003 - people are going there for the bug and closing means deletion is not far behind. Gotta see that bug.

Comment: If you hold right arrow in the textbox, you will immediately realize the problem

Comment: Declining, as this is rather rare. The tags have to be _just_ long enough to cause this issue, and though confusing, this is not something that most people will encounter.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The tags are there, they're just being aligned way to the left for some reason...

> [image: I'm over here sir...]

That `left: -378.5px` looks very suspicious.

Comment: Heh. The total width of those tags together in the edit box is more than the width of the box itself (666px, no devils involved) - the cursor goes to the end of the last tag, so guessing the browser wants that to be visible and adjusts the margins.

Comment: Having said that (and not given much thought to a fix), not sure what the right thing to do here is...

Answer (score 3):

With Firefix under Ubuntu and 1920x1080 diplay, that's what I'm seeing editing the question.

[image: This is what I was seeing]

If I remove the partially showing tag, I see the other ones with a some strange spacing. And that's my Eclipse build popup in that second image if you're wondering.

[image: Removed]