# In IE 11 the first tag tries to escape the tags box

Tags: bug, design, inline-tag-editor

When writing an question here on meta I noticed the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) tries to get away at the left side of the Tags box.

[image]

This only happens on IE11 (Win7/x64). I couldn't repro on Chrome or Firefox.

I and others have seen similar issues, [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236554/tag-input-box-is-misaligned-on-mso), [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229833/tags-feeling-a-little-shy-again), [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197571/158100) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277517/the-tags-are-disappearing-in-the-tag-box-again-even-worse-than-last-time), across browsers.

If there is time, can this be fixed for those poor IE11 users?

Comment: IE? Someone is still using this thing?! (I guess that the designers never thought  to test using that browser :-))

Comment: You had to make that one, didn't you?

Comment: Yup, can't resist... they just make it worse with newer versions, it's amazing more than irritating.

Comment: This is a rare issue but has come up before in various browsers: [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197565/the-case-of-the-tags-that-werent-there-because-they-were-scared-of-my-burninati) and [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277517/the-tags-are-disappearing-in-the-tag-box-again-even-worse-than-last-time)

Comment: @animuson but those are non-IE reports if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: It happens in *all* browsers, but the difference in browser font rendering causes certain cases to appear in only one or two browsers at a time.

Comment: It's escalating, happened now to [someone with Firefox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252886/not-all-tags-are-shown-when-trying-to-edit-a-post?lq=1)

Comment: Oh, this is no repro? Can someone confirm?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on IE11.

Comment: @DEAD I close voted it as no repro, so yes ...

Answer (score 1):

**Whom it may concern**

adding …

```css
.tag-editor + span {
  position: absolute;
}
```

will fix this issue in IE 11.

Comment: The `+` selector will select the element immediately after the tag editor, which is an overlay containing the description of what you type into that box. The span is not shown at all (`display: none`) when there are tags present, so no amount of modifying its properties would do anything. Did you perhaps mean to use `.tag-editor > span`? That would make more sense although I'm not completely sure why it would fix the issue.

Comment: @animuson you may be right. All I did was a quick code inspection. The final solution will be more complex, I assume. It is meant as a hint for the developers, nothing more. Maybe posting this as an answer was not the best idea. :-)