# Not all tags are shown when trying to edit a post

Tags: bug, tags, edits, inline-tag-editor

When trying to edit [this phys.SE question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/174495/conservation-of-energy-in-rotational-mechanics), the tag line becomes this:

[image]

Where two and a half tags are hidden, and it is impossible to get the two leftmost ones to show. The same happens when I try to use `edit` instead of `edit tags`, and at least [one other user](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20939015#20939015) has the same issue.

My operating system is Windows 7, browser is Firefox 37.0.1.

Comment: Also reported for IE11, most likely same root cause affecting several browsers then.